# Trying to pass a background color through intentPutExtra

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am trying to set the background color with `intentPutExtra` but it doesn't seem to change, this is my intent from the `MainActivity`:

```
  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ktmList.class);
                   intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this is how  I try to change the background color:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.models_list);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    int backgroundColor = intent.getIntExtra("backgroundColor", -1);

    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.models_rootView);
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```

and this is the models_list xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/models_rootView"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/models_list"
                android:padding="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rootView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundColor);` instead of `rootView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);`

Also change

```
intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", R.color.colorOrange);
```

That worked for me

Comment: now my app crashes  when I click the array with  
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ofir.motoinfo/com.ofir.motoinfo.brandlists.ktmList}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff

Comment: Still getting the same error, maybe the problem is in my intent.getIntExtra("backgroundColor", -1);?

first time using get extras, is this the proper way?

Comment: Oops. I missed that. No you are doing it wrong. Use getIntent().getIntExtra("backgroundColor", -1);